# Can I turn off Chromebook dev mode after installing Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation, chromebook

im looking to install ubuntu on my chromebook using dev mode, but i do not wish to have the white screen caused by dev mode even after installing it.
After installing ubuntu can i turn off developer mode without wiping the ubuntu, or is there a way to remove the white screen from dev mode?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot completely turn off dev mode unless you flash a new UEFI, but you can shorten the timeout for the screen from 30 seconds to 2 seconds.

There are two options. Run the [MrChromebox.Tech script](https://mrchromebox.tech/#fwscript), and do one of the followings.

```
 cd; curl -LO mrchromebox.tech/firmware-util.sh && sudo bash firmware-util.sh
```

1. You can install the full UEFI firmware. Then the current developer mode screen will be gone, and you will have to reinstall Ubuntu.
2. Alternatively, you can choose `3) Set Boot Option`, and set the timeout for the developer boot screen to 2 seconds (instead of the default 30 seconds, which is annoying). You will need to (temporarily) disable Firmware Write Protect to do this.

[image]